# Query to find all FK constraints, and their referenced table columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, referential-integrity

I have a large SQL 2012 database (100 tables), in which I need to find all constraints where the referential action is set to CASCADE (update or delete).

In [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877564/792888) I see that I can list the constraints using the following T-SQL (adapted slightly):

```
SELECT
    name,
    delete_referential_action_desc,
    update_referential_action_desc
FROM
    sys.foreign_keys
WHERE
    update_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE' OR
    delete_referential_action_desc = 'CASCADE';
```

This provides a useful list:

```
name        delete_referential_action_desc      update_referential_action_desc
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FK_name001  CASCADE                             CASCADE
FK_name002  CASCADE                             NO_ACTION
FK_name003  CASCADE                             NO_ACTION
```

However, is it possible to expand the code, so that for each constraint the respective table names and columns names are included, e.g.?

```
name        delete_referential_action_desc      update_referential_action_desc  ParentTable ParentCol   ChildTable  ChildCol
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FK_name001  CASCADE                             CASCADE                         Table1      Col1        Table2      Col2
```

I've tried different edits pulling in values from `sys.objects` but cannot figure out how it works, or whether that's even the correct approach.

## Update

Please note that I **do not want** to `ALTER` anything, or make any schema changes.  I just want to view a list so that I can perform further actions manually.  I do not have the confidence or experience to [edit this gigantic query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639982/792888) to pull out the salient points.

Comment: The second query in the duplicate will do this, you just need to add the where clause you've already identified to restrict the output to cascading keys.

Comment: But I don't want to `Alter` anything, I just want to *see* them

Comment: I understand that. The script can be altered slightly to output the definitions without actually running them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After two days of experimenting I've <s>got pretty close to what I need</s> finally solved it, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925753/792888) as a basis:

```
SELECT
    C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    PK.TABLE_NAME,
    CCU.COLUMN_NAME,
    FK.TABLE_NAME,
    CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    C.UPDATE_RULE,
    C.DELETE_RULE
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU ON PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
    ((C.UPDATE_RULE = 'CASCADE') OR (C.DELETE_RULE = 'CASCADE')) AND
    (FK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY')
ORDER BY
    PK.TABLE_NAME, 
    FK.TABLE_NAME;
```

Praise be to the digital Gods...(!)

Comment: Thank you for going to the effort to get it right. Since the new temporal tables may not have ON UPDATE CASCADE or DELETE, I had to find any such monsters in my big database. **Super-useful**!!